# node-webkit windows build where to store persistent data?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, node-persist

I am building a desktop app with node-webkit. I have used the nw-builder to build for windows 32 & windows 64 bit from my mac. The program is working fine in windows except that the files I use to store data is gone upon program exit.

The app is packed as a .pak file and I am assuming when the program is closed , all the files along with are erased. So when I start the app again , the persisted data is gone.

How can I persist data in Windows for node-webkit ?

I am using 'node-persist' package for my persistence. In Mac its creating a folder called 'persist' inside the .app file and writing files to that which works fine.

But in windows , due to the .pak file , the persisted files are lost when the program is closed. How do I fix this ? Is there a way to to store files outside the .pak. The .pak seems to be extracted to a temp location.

**UPDATE ( solved )**

I have used App.dataPath as described in [https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/App](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app)

excerpt :

> Get the application's data path in user's directory. Windows:
>   %LOCALAPPDATA%/; Linux: ~/.config/; OSX:
>   ~/Library/Application Support/ where  is the field in the
>   manifest.

[PopcornTime](https://popcorntime.io/) also uses the same in its database.js file. https://git.popcorntime.io/popcorntime/desktop/blob/master/src/app/database.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app

Personally, I used `localStorage`. For simple needs, it's very easy and mimics browser behaviour.

Comment: I am using 'node-persist' npm module and its writing to a file. I am not using any of the browser based storage. Its creating a file inside my root in a folder called persist. https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist. In the docs  there is an init option for file storage location 

storage.init({
    dir:'relative/path/to/persist', ....

I will try if this can create files outside the .pak file.

Comment: I have used App.dataPath as described in your answer and it served my purpose for windows & mac storage.